# PowerShell: Trying to find files modified after a certain date

Tags: powershell

Should be simple, right? But I can't get it to work

My code:

```
$StiNavn = "C:\TestDato"

foreach ($i in $StiNavn)
{
    if ($i.LastWriteTime -ge ('01/06/2021').Date )
            {
        Get-ChildItem $i | % { $_.FullName }
             }
 }
```

But all files gets returned, even files Edited today (also files created today).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `('01/06/2021').Date` should be `(Get-Date '01/06/2021').Date`

Comment: What are you iterating in `foreach ($i in $StiNavn)` ?? As far as we can see, `$StiNavn` is nothing but a string (looks like a directory path)

Answer (score 1):

StiNavn is just a string, you've not passed any files/objects into $StiNavn.
Running Get-ChildItem and then assigning it to variable will generate a collection of objects which you can then loop through using foreach

```
$StiNavn = Get-ChildItem "C:\TestDato" -recurse
```

You could also do something using where-object. An example is...

```
$StiNavn = Get-ChildItem "C:\TestDato" -recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}
```

Comment: Good answer.  Change `-recursive` to `-recurse` though